# Designing the database schema (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I am implementing a database to store details for my users. Normally I would create like this:

```
UserID    metafield1   metafield2   metafield3
1         value11      value12     value13
2         value21      value22     value23
3         value31      value32     value33
```

But looking at the databases in Wordpress, they have done it like this:

```
UserID    metafieldname   metafieldvalue
1         metafield1      value11
1         metafield2      value12
1         metafield3      value13
2         metafield1      value21
2         metafield2      value22
2         metafield3      value23
3         metafield1      value31
3         metafield2      value32
3         metafield3      value33
```

From what I see, it is easier to add/edit/remmove new metafields. You don't have to change the structure of the table.

There are will be no null cells in the second schema. However, for large amount of rows, the name of the metafields will take up space.

Is querying faster using the second schema?

I'm wondering what is the advantage of second approach over the first?

Thanks.

Comment: You already stated the advantage... Fields can be added/removed/modified without having to change the schema.  For a scenario with an inherently dynamic schema, this is a common approach.  The disadvantage is that is adds complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The query speed depends on what field you are searching and if that field is indexed. Also depends on how many rows there are in the table as well as what the datatype the column is.

If you were to query where UserId = somevalue there would be no significant speed difference returning the values assuming the datatypes are the same in both schemes.

If the metafields were indexed and queried upon you would then see subtle differences in speed.

I would recommend the second one you have listed for optimization purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The most important advantage of the second approach is that you will not have to change the structure of the table should you add more of your metafields.  This is a huge advantage over the long run.  Also this second approach will simplify your query statements, insert, and delete statements.